# How to search for an exact match of special characters in a string using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working on regex in python. I am very new to regex in python. 
As a part of my learning I have the following question

```
String1 = "[hello]"
Result = re.sub(re.compile("[.*?]>"),"", Result)
print(string)
```

Now my `Result` should be nothing

But if the `String1 = "[*hello]"`

Then my result should be `[*hello]`

Help me with this

Comment: ^[^a-zA-Z](.*) I think this is the regex you are looking for?

Comment: @AndreMotta maybe `0-9` as well?

Comment: @No one, I think you **must read this:** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Andre Motta Doesn't work can you give me exact code

Comment: @mikuszefski yeah so it'd be ^[^a-zA-Z0-9](\[\*) 

And what do you mean with it doesn't work? I just saw you need the regex to search stuff that starts with [* not only [ so that regex above should do the trick

Comment: @Andre Motta I think you did not get me. I should return the string as it is if it starts with "[*" else if it starts with "[" then I should return an empty string

Comment: @Andre Motta please give me  exact pattern you have given ^[^a-zA-Z](.*) In first comment and in second comment you are giving ^[^a-zA-Z0-9]([*). Is it (.*) Or ([*) please be clear

Comment: @Noone please ignore my comments here as i had missunderstood the question. I have provided a better and complete answer below!

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the wrong comments I was typing from my phone and read the question unclearly. Allow me to clarify now:

The regex you need is :

```
^(\[\*)[^ ]*
```

You can test it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/),

It will return a match if the strings starts with [* and return the exact match of the following string up until the next blank space, if it was something different you desired please comment your exact string ending if it exists.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot, another modification is needed. For example [* hi hello hey] this doesn't work. I should return the entire [*hi hello hey] can you Help me with that

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, as a test to your string:

```
my_str = '[hello] and [*hello]'
res = re.search('(\[\*\s?\w*\+?\w*)\]), my_str)#to also match closing bracket - (\[\*\w+)\]
print(res.group(0))
```

That will output `[*hello]` only
Since this has many variables..iI suggest you stray from regex

Comment: It helps, But if I want all those words that starts with "[*" and not "[" what should I do

Comment: Do you want the first match or the whole word,I have edited my answer to illustrate a case where words like `[*hello]`,`[*spam]`,`[*eggs]`,`[*foo]` would be matched

Comment: it worked perfect but if consider [* mi+Ed] something like this I need to return to the same [* mi+Ed] help me with this

Comment: The character '+' has special meaning in escape it., check my answer update and mark it as answer if it helped

Comment: At this point I have to ask..exactly what are you trying to do because this is getting us no where..my edit to my answer is as far as I can take you with the info you gave